# Reverse proxy with mod_proxy, preserve original request URL

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I've configured a reverse proxy using mod_proxy (Apache2) listening on 127.0.0.1:80, that proxies all the request to 127.0.0.1:8080

So I've configured mod_proxy like:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

When I request `http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar`, the app listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 gets the following request URL from mod_proxy:

http://127.0.0.1/bar

Instead I'd like to preserve the original request, and get:

http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try adding `/foo` to the right-hand side of your ProxyPass directives?  e.g. `ProxyPass /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried again and actually it DOES solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
```

Comment: while this is correct can we do this that /foo is running http://127.0.0.1/ and not with foo after it,
So that localhost/foo is actually running http://127.0.0.1/