# Problem with routes when accessing location

Tags: nginx

I have a problem which i dont know how to resolve:

When I enter example.com/privacy it opens url like this [www.example.com:82/privacy/](http://www.example.com:82/privacy/) which is not correct and site is not displayed

When I enter site.com/privacy/ then it opens correctly.

How can i fix it when i enter site site.com/privacy it would open privacy index.html file?

My setup is:

Reverse proxy in front of website which then proxy pass requests to nginx web server via port 82

Nginx reverse proxy site file

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;


  location / {
#    limit_req zone=MYZONE burst=100 nodelay;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://xxxxx:82;
  }


    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Web server site file

```
server {
    listen 82;

    root /var/www/xxxx.com/_site;
    index index.htm;

    location /privacy/ {
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158297/reverse-proxy-with-mod-proxy-preserve-original-request-url (it's ProxyPreserveHost on)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your nginx.conf file according to my nginx.conf. this configuration works for me.

```
server {
    listen example.com:80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen www.example.com:80;

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name  example.com;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        root /var/www/xxxx.com/_site/;
        index index.html;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tip, but didnt work, i think thats something on reverse proxy side, which i dont understand yet.